# Different Results for json_encode() PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

If i do this :

```
$new_arr = array(
0 => 'keyboard',
1 => 'mouse',
2 => 'computer'
);

print_r(json_encode($new_arr));
```

Output:

> ["keyboard","mouse","computer"]

But say i fetch all rows of "product" table from my database and i do this :

```
$product_with_id_map = array();
foreach($query as $result) {
$product_with_id_map[$result->id] = $result->name;
}
print_r(json_encode($product_with_id_map));
```

Output:

> {"0":"Keyboard","1":"mouse","2":"computer"}

I really need to retain the key of the array when i json_encode also can you tell me how to achieve the second output in the 1st example ?

Comment: Just so I get your question right: the second output form is the desired one, right?

Comment: yes exactly i want to retain array keys in my json_encode

Comment: *"I really need to retain the key of the array when i json_encode..."* Well, technically you have. The keys are the same in both examples. But the first one is an array, the other is just an object with property keys consisting entirely of digits. If the language decoding this JSON is JavaScript, it's a very subtle difference (as array keys are strings in JavaScript -- [yes, really](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)). Other languages may vary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm thank , pretty new to this json technology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the array to object.

```
$new_arr = array(
  0 => 'keyboard',
  1 => 'mouse',
  2 => 'computer'
);

print_r(json_encode((object)$new_arr));
// output: {"0":"keyboard","1":"mouse","2":"computer"}
```

***Addtion:***
If you use this result in javascript, I suggest you use the array, array is also object in javascript, besides, it provide more methods and `length` property to you.

Comment: yes perfect that works , can you please tell me why did i get different results ?

Comment: @user1537158 - because arrays work different to objects in JSON.

Comment: @xdazz: you don't even need to convert the array into object. The output of json_encode can contain keys, since he is using an incremental number sequence to construct array, the json_encode output is omitting the keys. That really does not effect when he convert that json_encoded string to array back, the keys will be back in incremental sequence. Try changing the key `1` to `4` and see the json_encode output

Comment: @xdazz , than will be accepting this answer in 4 mins , thank you again

Comment: @ShaktiSingh what are you implying here then ?

Comment: @ShaktiSingh Cast array to object is just to achieve the output the op desired. As I said, leave it to be an array in javascript is more convenient.

Comment: @user1537158: What I mean is you don't need that output

Comment: @ShaktiSingh the Fundamental reason for doing this is , that i pass the json encoded object from controller to view and in my view's JS i use it to populate a drop down , when a user selects a option in the dropdown in want the id to be retrieved and used not the product name *hope that makes sense*

Answer (score 8):

Use the options ([since PHP 5.3](http://php.net/json_encode)):

```
print_r(json_encode($product_with_id_map, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the indexes that are being returned from the data base are coming back as strings and so are being encoded in the JSON too. Where as when you're creating the array yourself you're setting them as integers and so they are being ignored.

You could either try

```
$new_arr = array(
'0' => 'keyboard',
'1' => 'mouse',
'2' => 'computer'
);

print_r(json_encode($new_arr));
```

or you could trun the array into an object which will preserve the indexes.

```
print_r(json_encode((object)$new_arr));
```

Comment: Your first piece of code won't work, it make no diference unless you cast the array to object.